# How do I get the Rust IntelliJ IDEA plugin to show autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: intellij-idea, rust

I use IntelliJ IDEA to develop in Rust, but after installing the [Rust plugin](https://intellij-rust.github.io/), the code auto-complete function doesn't work:

[image]

I hope IntelliJ IDEA would give me a hint for `String`, but I still need me to write it myself. Did I miss something?

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart, if it doesn't help, [file a bug](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mkaput gives the right [answer](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/1061#issuecomment-285267909):

> You have created a project in a directory which is not a Cargo project (you have two separate ones inside instead). Our requirement for almost any feature is that IntelliJ project root (~/rust in your situation) is also Cargo project/workspace root (it has Cargo.toml). Thanks to this we can firmly invoke cargo to get all information we need.
>
> tl;dr make separate projects inside each: hello_cargo and guessing_game :-)

Comment: Note: if they support the [workspace](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-workspace--field-optional), then you have a single project. Just put a `Cargo.toml` with a `[workspace]` section at the root.

Answer (score -1):

I use IntelliJ Community Edition on MacOS and auto complete works fine. Try install racer crate and restart IDE:

`cargo install racer`

Comment: As much as possible, answers should be **definitive**. "Have you tried ...?" is a comment, not an answer.